# Modo de resolver este código

Tags: javascript, array

No me sale esta petición:

Crea una función arrayDeArrays que recibirá un array array y el indice indice, devuelve el primer elemento del array accedido previamente con el índice del parámetro. Si el array no existe, devuelve -1 Ejemplo:

```
arrayDeArrays([[5, 7, 99], [67, 89, 21], [40, 27, 57]], 1) // 67
```

He intentado resolverlo mediante un "for" pero no obtengo el resultado esperado:

```
const arrayDeArrays = (array, indice) =>{
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[array.index] == indice){
            return array [index] [0]
        }else{
            return false
        }       
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario recorrer el arreglo con una estructura cíclica. Bastará con que verifiques si el índice recibido es menor o igual a la extensión del arreglo menos una unidad (el primer índice de un arreglo es cero), además de que el valor del índice no sea negativo.

Esto se vería más o menos así:

```javascript
const arrayDeArrays = (array, indice) => {
    if (indice >= 0 && indice <= array.length - 1){
        return array[indice][0];
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
};
```

Y si lo quieres en una sola línea (tiene la misma funcionalidad, pero puede ser menos legible para algunas personas):

```javascript
const arrayDeArrays = (array, indice) => indice >= 0 && indice <= array.length - 1 ? array[indice][0] : -1;
```

Un ejemplo en uso con la forma *legible*:

```js
const arrayDeArrays = (array, indice) => {
    if (indice >= 0 && indice <= array.length - 1){
        return array[indice][0];
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
};

console.log(arrayDeArrays([[5, 7, 99], [67, 89, 21], [40, 27, 57]], 1));
console.log(arrayDeArrays([[5, 7, 99], [67, 89, 21], [40, 27, 57]], 4));
```

Y otro con la forma corta:

```js
const arrayDeArrays = (array, indice) => indice >= 0 && indice <= array.length - 1 ? array[indice][0] : -1;
console.log(arrayDeArrays([[5, 7, 99], [67, 89, 21], [40, 27, 57]], 1));
console.log(arrayDeArrays([[5, 7, 99], [67, 89, 21], [40, 27, 57]], 4));
```

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras ¿Cuál es el problema con los saludos? No le veo sentido al hecho de editar mi respuesta para eliminarlos. ¿Existe alguna regla dentro del reglamento interno que lo considere como *ruido* o que, de plano, penalice su uso? Y si así fuera, sería por demás risible.

Comment: No se penaliza su uso, sólo se desaconseja. No aportan nada a la respuesta, más allá de interacción en un sitio de por sí *impersonal*.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Es una excusa insuficiente. Los saludos son una muestra de educación, cortesía y respeto para con quien uno se está dirigiendo. Su finalidad no es la de *aportar* algo a la respuesta, sino la de mostrar lo dicho, respeto y cortesía. En virtud de ello, no tiene sentido retirarlos.

Comment: [Aquí](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) puedes leer más sobre el tema. Es un post en inglés. Presta atención al apartado *Making a good impression*.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Ya lo había leído. No se *desaconseja* el uso de los saludos, sino que meramente se explica que no hay *necesidad* de emplearlos, esto entendido dentro del contexto del contenido de la solución que aporta una respuesta. Pero, como ya lo había dicho, los saludos no tienen por finalidad generar un aporte a la respuesta, sino tan solo demostrar respeto y cortesía, criterios fundamentales en cualquier proceso de interacción sana y pacífica. De manera que, una vez más, no tiene sentido retirarlos.

Comment: Este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no de saludos y cortesía. Pero en fin, cada quien entiende lo que puede

Comment: Estás en un error, Mauricio. El hecho de que este sea un sitio de preguntas y respuestas no implica el hecho de tener que obviar los más elementales criterios de educación durante la interacción con nuestros semejantes. El respeto y la cortesía no tienen por qué ser excluidos, ni en este ni en ningún otro contexto en el que se entable un diálogo con otras personas. Es una cuestión ciertamente básica de ética, la cual puedo entender que no comprendas cómo o por qué tenga sentido aquí, pero que no por ello deja de ser importante en cualquiera de nuestras interacciones con los demás. Un saludo.

Comment: [_No uses firmas, taglines o saludos_](/help/behavior) y [_Saludar o no saludar_](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4282) (Spoiler: saludar es una forma de ruido) :) Las respuestas son para todos, no para un usuario en particular.

Comment: @padaleiana Si bien es cierto que las respuestas publicadas aquí pueden ser leídas por todos quienes visiten el sitio, el saludo individual es una muestra de educación, respeto y cortesía para con quien elabora la pregunta. Estoy de acuerdo con lo que se explica en la publicación que enlazas acerca de saludos que *no tienen sentido*, como los que indican un horario del día o, peor aun, lo que son innecesariamente extensos, pero creo que habrás advertido que ninguno de los saludos que empleo cae en estas categorías.

Comment: @padaleiana El tema de que un saludo pueda ser considerado como *ruido*, amén de lo expuesto en el debate del enlace y de lo que interpreto de todo lo dicho aquí, es evidentemente subjetivo. Personalmente no encuentro *ruidoso* iniciar una respuesta con un saludo sucinto; por lo contrario, es una buena manera de entablar un diálogo con la persona que pregunta, hecho que, por consecuencia lógica, tiende a derivar en la replicación del ejemplo; y si se puede generar que se replique el buen hábito de saludar antes de dirigirse a alguien, pues, enhorabuena.

Comment: Dicho lo anterior, continuaré saludando de la misma manera en la que lo vengo haciendo. Si los moderadores del sitio consideran necesario aplicar penalidades o, de plano, suspender mi cuenta, que lo hagan. No pienso dejar de hacer algo que forma parte de mis principios de conducta y que, obviamente, considero moralmente correctos. Un saludo.

Comment: Los comentarios no están hechos para debates. Podés acceder al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872) o hacer tu propia pregunta en Meta exponiendo tus argumentos (en formato _Q&A_, claro está).

Comment: Hola @Alexis88, lamento tener que decir, que es inútil tu esfuerzo por hacer entender la normas básicas de educación, me alegra que seas parte de la comunidad, sigue siendo como eres, y acepta que hay "cosas" que no van a cambiar.

Comment: Gracias por la comprensión, @MarcePuente. De hecho, hasta me pareció irónico que, en plena campaña de *huelga* de los moderadores por la introducción de cambios generados mediante IA, haya tal oposición hacia aspectos tan humanos como lo son el saludo y el respeto. Pero, en fin. Que quede a consciencia de cada uno lo que decida al respecto. Un abrazo.

Comment: Hola, a mi también me gustan los saludos. Aquí una forma aún más corta `const arrayDeArrays = (a, i) => a[i]?.at(0) || -1` por si deseas incluirla en tu respuesta

Comment: ¡Hola, @Yussef! Es un excelente ejemplo con el operador de encadenamiento opcional. Mientras más y mejor se aproveche las facilidades que ofrece ES6, los resultados en código irán progresando en igual medida. Un cordial saludo, Yussef.

Comment: Hablando de reglas, también existe reglas para editar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing#:~:text=Las%20ediciones%20deben%20ser%20sustanciales. Saludos cordiales a todos.